# Find characteristic polynomial for linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a linear operator $L:P_2(\mathbb{R})\to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ where

$L(\alpha+\beta X)=(3\alpha+2\beta)+(\alpha+2\beta)X, \alpha ,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$,

I want to find the following for $L$:

1. The characteristic polynomial for $L$
2. Eigenvalues for $L$ and bases for the eigenspaces.

In order to find the characteristic polynomial, I first need to find the standard matrix representation (SMR) of $L$. A basis for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathcal{V}=(1,X)$. That gives me an isomorphism:

$L_{\mathcal{V}}:\mathbb{R}^2\to P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

How do I continue from here?

I really want to understand the process of finding the bases for the eigenspaces.

Comment: My guess is that $L(\alpha+\beta X)=(3\alpha+2\beta)+(\alpha+2\beta)X$. Am I right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, edited.

Comment: Observe that $L(1) = 3+X$ and $L(X) = 2+2X.$ Does it ring the bell?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 No, how do you get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $L(1) = 3+X$ and $L(X) = 2+2X.$ So the standard matrix representation of $L$ is $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

So the characteristic polynomial of $L$ is $x^2 - 5x+ 4=0$ and hence the eigenvalues are $1$ and $4.$

Now consider the equations $$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix} = 4 \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Find any non-zero solutions to both of the equations to get the bases for the eigenspace of $L.$

You may check that $\left \{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right \}$ is one of the bases for the eigenspace of $L.$

Comment: How do you get $L(1)=3+X$?

Comment: @samsepi0l put $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta=0$ in the given definition of $L.$ Then you will be able to see that.

Comment: How do you get that $\alpha=1,\beta=0$ from L(1)? Sorry about a stupid question.

Comment: What is $\alpha+ \beta X$ if $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta=0$?

Comment: Where do you get the two matrix equations from? What kind of theorem are you referencing, so I can look it up?

Comment: It is called the matrix representation of a linear transformation. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix